# how to write select option in cake php and show the result in options

Tags: php

```
<select>
<?php $result=mysql_query('select id from contact');
while($row=$result){
$id = $row['id'];
?>
<option value='<?php echo $id; ?>'><?php echo $id; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select >
```

How to write this select box in cakephp ..

Comment: $options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
echo $this->Form->select('gender', $options);

Comment: how to write query inside select tag

Comment: Please you logic implement in controller

Comment: $result=$this->Contact->query('select id from contact');         $this->set('result',$result);

Comment: will u plz explain me briefly.. I am fresher for this cake php.

Comment: yaah, first you make a controller

Comment: class ItemController extends AppController{ public $item = array('Item', 'Item');  public function index() {
   $this->set('item', $this->Item->find('all'));
    }}

Comment: this is my controller code

Comment: which code i have to add to the controller .. which code i have to add to view part

Comment: above class is your controller

Comment: I added $result=$this->Contact->query('select id from contact'); $this->set('result',$result); in controller. what abt view part code ?

Comment: Contact is replace by Item

Comment: Its displaying error .. will u send me controller part and view part code separately ..

Comment: will u send me code to wvswvs4@gmail.com.

Comment: I've changed the tags, there is no CakePHP specific code at all in this question. Just a *deprecated* mysql_* function call.

Answer (score 2):

Make a list query in your controller (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html):

```
$results = $this->Model->find('list', $options);
```

and then add it to the form element in your view (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html):

```
$this->Form->input('Model.field', array('options' => $results));
```